# GtkTreeView, select/unselect row

Tags: treeview, gtk, pygtk

I have a simple TreeView with some entries and I need to receive a signal when a row is selected or unselected and retrieve the selected model's content.

```
def on_row_select(tree):
    model, iter = tree.get_selection().get_selected()
    print(model[iter][0])
...
treeview.connect('cursor-changed', on_row_select)
```

It works fine with selecting; however, when the row is unselected I expected `iter` to be `None` (according to [manual](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeselection.html#method-gtktreeselection--get-selected)), but the `iter` of previously selected element is given instead.
How can I check whether the row was uselected?

Comment: `cursor-changed` is the wrong signal; that's for when the cell with keyboard focus (the 1px box around a cell, usually in the selected row but not always) has changed. You want to connect to the `changed` signal of the GtkTreeSelection.

Comment: @andlabs Is that new with gtk3? I seem to remember I've always used cursor-changed (with the expected result :) (Ok - checked. Well, learned something new... Though cursor-changed very frequently coincides with the same function...)

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing I'm a bit worried about `changed` signal is:  
"Emitted whenever the selection has **(possibly)** changed."
It may cause some issues if, occasionally, it won't be emitted.  
I'm also wondering why `cursor-changed` doesn't work properly.

Comment: The discussion after that explains what it means by possibly: "Please note that this signal is mostly a hint. It may only be emitted once when a range of rows are selected, and it may occasionally be emitted when nothing has happened." The first part is only relevant to multiple selection; the second part just tells you about spurious messages. If you're doing single-selection, you'll get the signal every time the selection happens. (Otherwise, lots of software would be broken by now...) If you're using multiple-selection, you can't guarantee that every new item has its own `changed`...

Comment: ...(for instance, if the user holds down Shift and clicks two items to select a whole range all at once). You'll have to prepare for these situations. `cursor-changed` doesn't work properly because it doesn't deal with selection. It deals with something called keyboard focus. Occasionally, if you click on your tree view and then press Up or Down to navigate, you'll see that the current item gets a 1px box around it. You can hold down Control and the arrow keys to change the keyboard focused item. You'll then see that the focused item is not always equal to the current selection. ...

Comment: ... (Press Space to select that item and watch what happens.)